# How to set ExecStop command for with quotes?

Tags: shell, systemctl

I created a service using systemd. The service file is as follow.

```
Description=Contents Copy Copier

[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=always
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/ccCopier /etc/ccCopier.cfg
KillMode=none
ExecStop=/usr/bin/mysql -u root -proot ContentsCopy -e "update stock set Copier= 'quiesce' where Stock='`/usr/bin/hostname`'"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I execute ExecStop command on command line, it runs properly. However, when I execute systemctl stop, it does not work. I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: Multiply posted at https://stackoverflow.com/q/62296163/340790 .

Comment: `ccCopier` should be instructed to not fork. http://jdebp.uk./FGA/unix-daemon-design-mistakes-to-avoid.html

Answer (score 2):

The back-tick notation is expanded by your shell. systemd is not running your command in a shell so you can't use this notation. You should be able to replace this line by:

```
ExecStop=/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/mysql -u root -proot ContentsCopy -e "update stock set Copier= \'quiesce\' where Stock=\'`/usr/bin/hostname`\'"'
```

Comment: I also changed 'quiesce' to \'quiesce\' and then it works.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Good catch, I updated my answer!